# Group and Combine Text Fields Using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection of user reviews and I'm trying to combine all the reviews by user so I can run some NLP analysis on them. This feels like it should be easy, but I'm missing something with how Mongo treats strings.

My documents look like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('57e079d3e3874f12ad721f70'),
 'atmosphere': 5,
 'review_id': 63,
 'dedication': 3,
 'orgName': 'Some Organization',
 'enabled': True,
 'accessibility': 3,
 'efficiency': 3,
 'orgId': '57e05e0de3874f121d516616',
 'user': '5809f2c0bc0a53eb49eac583',
 'date': '10/20/15 0:00',
 'quality': 3,
 'orgId_orig': 1098,
 'description': 'Here is some sample text'
}
```

I've tried this:

```py
    agg_result = revs.aggregate( [
       { "$group": { "_id": "$user", "mergedText": { "$mergeObjects": "$description"  } } }
    ])

for i in agg_result:
    print(i)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
OperationFailure: $mergeObjects requires object inputs, but input "Here is some sample text" is of type string
```

My expected output would be

```
{
'userId1':{'mergedText':'joined descriptions from this user'},
'userId2':{'mergedText':'this users descriptions'},
'userId3':{'mergedText':'all descriptions from this user'}
}
```

where the various userIds are Mongo ObjectIds from the 'user' field.

I'm brand new to Mongo and this has been tripping me up for awhile. Thank you.

Comment: Done, thank you for letting me know to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this , merge object needs objectbut your description is string you could push in array

```
agg_result = revs.aggregate( [
       { "$group": { "_id": "$user", "mergedText": { "$push": "$description"  } } }
    ])

for i in agg_result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to tweak this a little bit to format the output (which I had forgotten to post an example of when you answered - so that's on me), but this answers the question. I don't have enough reputation yet to cast a vote, but I did click the up arrow.

Comment: Thank you , update your question what you need and and notify me